# directory and __autoload function

Tags: php

```
$name = 'Model_Two';
str_replace('_','/',$name);
```

I need replace in __autoload function Model_Two to Two/Model_Two.class.php but i dont want using in autoload implode and explode how it work ? My functions have name Model_Two, Controller_Two and this is good. But my directory tree in framework , mvc  is app/controllers/User/Controller_User.class.php.

I cant find method to repair my __autoload function. Maybe directory tree is wrong ?

Comment: Why don't you want to use explode and implode?

Comment: What about an autoloaded class with the name `_etc_passwd`?

Answer (score 0):

Use an existing naming convention and autoloader: [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

`require 'app/' . lcfirst(str_replace('_', 's/', $name)) . '/' . $name . '.php';`